# Ionic - Angular2 Invalid argument '[object Object]' for pipe 'DatePipe'

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have an order form with the following section:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-icon ios="ios-time" md="md-time" item-left></ion-icon>
  <ion-label> Start Time:</ion-label>
  <ion-note item-right> {{order.startTime | date: 'HH:mm'}}</ion-note>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
  <ion-icon ios="ios-time" md="md-time" item-left></ion-icon>
  <ion-label> End Time:</ion-label>
  <ion-note item-right> {{order.endTime | date: 'HH:mm'}}</ion-note>
</ion-item>

</ion-list>

<ion-toolbar *ngIf="view === 'order'">
<button ion-button (click)="submit()" block>Confirm Order</button>
</ion-toolbar>
```

The order information is pulled through fine and the dates are formatted correctly (without throwing an error) however selecting the submit button then throws the 'invalid argument' error.

The submit function only writes to DB and redirects. I also use this view in several places as a template for displaying order information and the only time it throws an error is during the order process.

Why is it only when re-directing that the error is thrown?

Any help or suggestions would be great!

UPDATE:
The submit button was connection to a collection in Ionic DB then writing a new object:

```
orders.insert(this.order);
```

Which was working fine but the error was throwing, changing the write operation to write each value explicitly has seemed to fix the problem:

```
orders.insert({
    name: this.order.name,
    etc...
}
```

Comment: can you try this and mention type of buttons( like button, submit reset) because as you mentioned filter pipe for date formatted properly(without throwing an error), type is necessary to mention because every browser has its different default type, you can try may be it works?

Comment: Not sure whether to post the possible fix as a solution or just close the question?

Comment: Can you put a JSON you used for this ion-list?